# Xcode 15 beta does not allow run script access to .git/HEAD and Info.plist

Tags: ios, xcode, run-script

To access the current git branch and commit, I have been using [this script](https://egeek.me/2013/02/09/xcode-insert-git-build-info-into-ios-app/#disqus_thread) successfully for a long time.
However, with Xcode 15.0 beta, the script has no longer access to the git and Info.plist files. I am getting these errors:

```
error: Sandbox: git(64989) deny(1) file-read-data <MyFolder>/.git/HEAD  
error: Sandbox: PlistBuddy(64994) deny(1) file-read-data <MyFolder>/Info.plist
```

Is it possible to allow access to these files again?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your build settings, you can set "User Script Sandboxing" to "No".

[image: Screenshot of setting "User Script Sandboxing" to no in Xcode 15]

Comment: solved my "Xcode 15 Sandbox: PlistBuddy deny(1) file-read-data Info.plist" issue, thanks

Answer (score 4):

For me, adding the files that `PlistBuddy` is about to edit to the `Output Files` of the `Run Script` did fix the issue.
This is probably more safe than disabling the whole sandboxing.